# inject when used is giving errors while angular testing

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner

### My Module is :

```
var app = angular.module('customer',
[
    'customerAPI',
    'uldbfilters',
    'ngRoute',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'nvd3',
    'chart.js',
    'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker',
    'ui.dateTimeInput',
    'LocalStorageModule',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngMaterial'
]);
```

### My karma config file is :

```
module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({
   basePath: '',
   frameworks: [
       'jasmine',
       'jasmine-matchers'
   ],
   files: [
       '../../static/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
       '../../static/bower_components/jquery-*/jquery-*.js',
       '../../static/bower_components/jquery-*/**/jquery-*.js',
       '../../static/bower_components/angular-charts/chart.js',
       '../../static/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
       '../../static/bower_components/angular-date-time-input/src/dateTimeInput.js',
       '../../static/bower_components/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/js/datetimepicker.js',
       '../../static/bower_components/angular-*/angular-*.js',
       '../../static/bower_components/angular-*/**/*.js',
       '../../static/rest/app/*.js',
       '../../static/rest/app/client/**/*.js',
       'test_suits_client/*.js'
   ],
   exclude: [
       '../../static/bower_components/angular-*/angular-*.min.js',
       '../../static/bower_components/angular-*/**/*.min.js',
       '../../static/bower_components/angular-*/**/index.js',
       '../../static/bower_components/angular-*/**/gulpfile.js',
       '../../static/bower_components/angular-*/**/karma.conf.js',
       '../../static/bower_components/angular-*/**/Gruntfile.js',
       '../../static/bower_components/angular-*/**/browserify.test.js'
   ],
   preprocessors: {},
   reporters: ['spec'],
   port: 9876,
   colors: true,
   logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
   autoWatch: true,
   browsers: [
      'Firefox'
   ],
   singleRun: false,
   concurrency: Infinity
}
```

### My test suite is :

```
describe('Customer Application uldb module functionality', function() {
    beforeEach(module('customer'));
        var scope;
        beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope){
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
        }));
        it('Sample spec to test 2 + 2', function() {
            expect(2 + 2).toEqual(4);
        });
    });
});
```

### Now when i run karma, It is showing an exception of

minErr/<@/home/vhosts/uldb/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
    loadModules/<@/home/vhosts/uldb/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4640:15
    forEach@/home/vhosts/uldb/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:321:11
    loadModules@/home/vhosts/uldb/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4601:5
    createInjector@/home/vhosts/uldb/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4523:19
    workFn@/home/vhosts/uldb/static/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3074:44
    [3]http://localhost:9876/context.js:162:7

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not regarding to $inject and it is purely based on your files loading in karma conf.js. I missed to load a library, in which current loading libraries is dependant on.